# Search for a string in a list of strings

Tags: javascript, string, binary-search-tree, trie

I have a list of strings & I want to check that a specific string is not found in it. 
I use javascript, so I was wondering if a Trie or  binary search method would be better. Is there something pre-implemented that can be used for something like this ?

Here is the object :

```
var TheObject = { "TheItemId": Index, "TheItemText": NewItem };
```

I have a list of this objects, when I insert a new Item, I want to be sure "TheItemText" doesn't contain any similar texts.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Trie or w binary" ?

Comment: if it is a valid json string you can do using inbuilt functions.

Comment: inbuilt functions like what ?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript objects can be treated as hash-maps. So you would keep an object `var strings = {}`. Whenever you add object to the list, you would also add property to the `strings` object: `strings[text] = true`. Then you can easily check whether the text has been added before with `if (strings[text]) {`. Downside of this solution is that you must track changes in two collections (your list and `strings`). Maybe you do not need list at all, then you can use `strings[NewItem] = { 'TheItemId': Index, 'TheItemText': NewItem }`. Changes to 'TheItemText' and the property name must be still coordinated.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something like this work?

```
typeof TheList.TheItemText === 'undefined'
```

Comment: I can check it using the command, but I'm asking about the best algorithm to do it